# Routing to dashboard after successfully Logging In (React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

I've created a simple login form that uses authentication through firebase but i am unable to redirect to another page after successfully logging in. I am using browser router and there is no error on the console (nothing happens)

`

```
uploadHandler=e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email,this.state.password)
  .then((user) => {
    console.log("Signed In");
    <Router>
      <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
    </Router>
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    console.log(errorCode);
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    this.setState({emailError:errorMessage})
  });
  this.setState({emailError:null})
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. That's not how you use `Router`, I'd return something like: `<Redirect to='/' />`
2. You totally misunderstand React, I think. You place JSX code inside your function - what for? The only case I can think of is if you used your function inside a `render()` of some component like so:

```
<div>
    {uploadHandler()}
</div>
```

(which we both know you aren't :), and even then you'd have to explicitly `return` that JSX, or remove the `{}` brackets...

What I'd recommend is setting some state variable in case of a successfull auth request `this.setState({ auth: true });` and placing your redirect inside `return()`:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.auth) return <Redirect to='/' />
    else ...
}
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use useHistory hook to redirect. It is quite simple. First import it, then initialize it inside the component and finally you can use it in your code.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const MyComponent = () => {
  let history = useHistory();

  return (
   <button onClick={history.push("/home")} />
  );
}
```